# How to edit Date and time picked by user from UIDate picker, in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker

I am trying to schedule local notification at 8AM on the days where user have appointment. Just like an advanced reminder to notify user that they have an appointment today.

I am getting a data and converting it in to datecomponents to schedule notification.

what is the way to read user selected data and edit just hour to 8AM?

Comment: To be clear... you're trying to make UIDatePicker only show the hours?

Comment: sorry if im not clear. 

IN my app, a user will pick date and time for notificaiton. 

i would like to send another notification extra at particular time in morning on the selected date.

Comment: Ok clear... I will look into it.

Comment: Ok, so you want the user to pick a date and time. Then you want to force the time of day of the user's chosen date to a specific time (8AM, for example)?

Comment: Yes you are right

Answer (score 0):

To do that, take the user's selected date, and use the Calendar function

```
date(bySettingHour:minute:second:of:matchingPolicy:repeatedTimePolicy:direction:)
```

So if you have a date `userDate` that the user selected in a date picker, use

```
guard let eightAM = Calendar.current.date(
      bySettingHour: 8, 
      minute: 0, 
      second: 0, 
      of: userDate) else {
    fatalError("Can't set time of user-entered date. Exiting.")
}
```

(The function should never fail, so I wrote the code using a guard let and a call to `fatalError()`.)

Comment: Will try this :)

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot, I have got what I wanted. 

your code piece worked but with little tweak. Posting this for anyone who is looking for same

Comment: let date = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 08, minute: 0, second: 0, of: Date())!
        guard let eightAM = Calendar.current.date(
              bySettingHour: 08,
              minute: 0,
              second: 0,
              of: reminderDate) else {
            fatalError("Can't set time of user-entered date. Exiting.")
        }
        let triggerDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year,.month,.day,.hour,.minute,.second,],
          from: reminderDate)
    
        let trigger1 = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDate,
          repeats: false)

Comment: You should edit your question to show your code, or post your own answer. Comments are completely unformatted and all but impossible to read.